# Construct MediaStore Query uri for multiple folders on sdcard

Tags: android, mediastore

Good day, i am trying to return images from different specific folders in an SD Card through a MediaStore Query. So far, i can successfully query for a single folder but am getting stuck in how to do it for multiple folders. 
code is like this:

```
cursor = getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, img, 
     MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA + " like ? ", new String[]{"%" + "dcim" + "%"}, null);
```

i tried constructing something like this and other similar queries, but its not working:

```
cursor = getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, img, 
MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA + " like ? ", new String[]{"%" + "dcim" + "%","%" + "downloads" + "%" }, null);
```

please any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: anyone with any idea how to write this?..

Comment: hmmm.. no ideas or links where to find information on this?..

Answer (score 2):

Should be something like that:

```
cursor = getContentResolver().query(
    MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, 
    img,
    MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA + " like ? OR "+MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA+" like ?", 
    new String[]{"%" + "dcim" + "%","%" + "downloads" + "%" }, 
    null);
```

Answer (score 0):

A one possible solution is to use multiple queries for every specific location and then join them with [CursorJoiner](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/CursorJoiner.html) like already showed here:

[Android Can I use JOIN at mediastore query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6526212/android-can-i-use-join-at-mediastore-query)